# Largest filtration for a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, filtrations

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be independent random variables where $P(X_n = 2^{n}) = P(X_n = -2^{n}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $M_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Find the largest filtration, such that $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale.

I know the sigma-field $\sigma(M_1,...,M_n)$ is the smallest filtration that $M_n$ is adapted to, but how can I think of the largest?

In the end, all I need is that for $M_{n+1}$, $\mathcal{F_n}$ contains the informations for all previous $X_k$ and no information at tall on $X_{n+1}$

I am grateful for any tip and piece of advice

Comment: Which order is put on the collection of filtrations such that $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale? A remark: if $(M_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a martingale for $(\mathcal F_n)$ then it is also the case for $(\mathcal G_n)$ where $\mathcal G_n$ is generated by $\mathcal F_n$ and $\mathcal H$, a  $\sigma$-algebra independent of $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots)$.

Comment: What do you mean with which order is put on the collection of filtrations? And ad $(\mathcal{G_n})$: do you mean $\mathcal{G_n} = \sigma(\mathcal{F_n} \cup \mathcal{H})$ ? Can $\mathcal{H}$ be an arbitrary sigma algebra as long as it independent of $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n,....)$ ?

Comment: Yes for the second part of your comment. For  the first one, in order to decide of a largest filtration, we should define how we can determine whether the filtration $(\mathcal F_i^1)_i$ is larger than the filtration  $(\mathcal F_i^2)_i$.

Comment: The decisive criterion is the cardinality of the set : the filtration ($\mathcal{F_{i}}^{1})_i)$ is larger than than ($\mathcal{F_{i}}^{2})_i$ if for all $i$, $\vert \mathcal{F_i}^{1} \vert $ $\ge$ $\vert \mathcal{F_i}^{2} \vert$ - is that what you were asking ?